# npm-request with XHR.withCredentials?

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest, npm-request

For keeping session information as cookies and having CORS along with it, XHR has [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) option along with [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) response Header to make the browser send the cookies for each requests.

I would like to achieve the same (withCredentials) in npm-request package. Is there any way for this ? :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `withCredentials: true` in request options and your module bundler will take care of the rest :)